# Netgear FVS318G VPN connection issue

Tags: vpn

I'm trying to setup a VPN connection from my mobile (Android) or laptop via mobile to an office network connected to the Internet using FVS318G.

The configuration on the server side seems to be okay according to manuals, but I'm unable to connect from the outside (using the Android system VPN client or NetworkManager-vpnc).

The VPN log of the FVS318G shows the message:

```
2011 Jan 31 07:37:49 [FVS318g] [IKE] Could not find configuration for *.*.*.*[500]_
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I have gotten farther than you by using the DynDNS app from the market and thus having both ends with a fqdsn. I am on Android 2.2.1 and using AES-128 and SHA-1.

The first SA works but then a subsequent SA is requested by my FVS318G and the Android device doesn't respond. I'm in main mode.

You would think there would be a Prosafe client for Android out there somewhere.